# how to populate city corresponding selected state

Tags: linq

i have a xml below.now i want to populate all city in drop downlist according to selected state(code is given below)but i am getting only first one city instead of all city.
how to get all city.please see code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<states>
  <state> 
    <stateid>1</stateid> 
    <city>umr</city> 
    <city>kat</city> 
    <city>jpl</city> 
    <city>bpl</city>
  </state>
  <state> 
    <stateid>2</stateid> 
    <city>mumbai</city> 
    <city>dadar</city> 
    <city>ghat</city> 
    <city>kanjur</city> 
  </state> 
</states>
```

here 1 is stateid,with in state have city like umr.kat,jpl bpl.

```
public static List<statecs> GetStateFromXML(string getstateid)
{ 
   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(
           HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("stateXML.xml")); 
   var states = from state in xmlDoc.Descendants("state") 
                where state.Element("stateid").Value == getstateid 
                select new statecs { City = state.Element("city").Value, };
   return states.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: Why not put the `stateid` as an attribute on `state`?

Answer (score 0):

this might work...not tested nor compiled

```
    // fetch states first
    var states = from state in xmlDoc.Descendants("state")
      where state.Element("stateid").Value == getstateid
      select state;

    // for found states select the city.
    var cities = from city in states.Descendants("city")
                  select new statecs { City = city.Value, };    

    return cities.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SelectMany:

```
return xmlDoc.Descendants("state")
    .Where(state => state.Element("stateid").Value == getstateid)
    .SelectMany(state => state.Elements("city").Select(city => new statecs { City = city.Value }))
    .ToList();
```